# Get all security groups under specific folder

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

Active Directory.
How can I get all security groups in a specific folder?

[image: AD]

Say my domain is "cfs". I am going to list all security groups in cfs\CHC_APP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would do something like this:

```
DirectoryEntry searchBase = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=CHC_APP,DC=cfs");
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(searchBase);
searcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=group)(objectClass=group)(groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2147483648))";

SearchResultCollection results = searcher.FindAll();

//do something with results
```

Comment: If I want to get the groups of the current user, what is the filter? And how to iteriate the results?

Comment: You can get follow the bottom example from http://lkarolak.wordpress.com/2010/11/17/finding-active-directory-users-group-membership-in-c/. The call to GetAuthorizationGroups() returns the groups for that user which you can then iterate through.

Comment: that filter seem not to collect the builtin security groups